# Upper bound on the largest singular value

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If I have any matrix $W \in R^{nxm}$, and matrices $U, V$ where the following properties hold:

1) $U^{T}W =0$

2) $WV = 0$

I want to show that the upper bound of the largest singular value of the matrix $A = UV^{T}+W$ is equal to that of $W$, **I'm getting a weird result and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here.
Here's my attempt**

if $W = PSR^{T}$ is the SVD of $W$ , where $P,R$ are orthogonal then we have the following

$U^{T}W = 0 = U^{T}PSR = 0$ by multiplying both sides by $R^{T}S^{-1}$
we get that $ 0 = U^{T}P $.
By a similar argument we can get that $R^{T}V = 0 $
Now

$P^{T}AR = P^{T}(UV^{T}+W)R = S $. so we have 
$ A = PSR^{T} = W$ so $UV^{T} = 0$.
**I'm not sure that this is a correct result**

**Note: All the matrices here are composed of real numbers**

Comment: @michael-grant I have added the convex optimization tag because that problem is used to compute the subgradient of the trace norm of matrix.

Comment: Understood. But by the same logic, lots of questions about linear algebra, calculus, etc. should have that tag because they are used somewhere in convex optimization. You've (rightly!) isolated the problem from that context, so the tag is not warranted.

Comment: But $VW=0$ does not imply that $R^TV=0$. All it gives is that $VP=0$ which I can't see to be very useful here.

Comment: @AlgebraicPavel Sorry for that it was supposed to be $WV=0$, fixed it.

Comment: I see. But anyway, you only get that $P^T(UV^T)R=0$ does not necessarily imply that $UV^T=0$. It is not clear to me what version of SVD (full, "economy") you use. If it is the economy version, then my previous comment applies, otherwise you cannot multiply with $S^{-1}$.

Comment: @AlgebraicPavel to use $P^{T}(UV^{T}R = 0$ fact, I did that
$P^{T}AR = P^{T}(UV^{T}+W)R = S $. so we have 
$ A = PSR^{T} = W$ so $UV^{T} = 0$.

Comment: As I said, it depends what version of SVD you use. Either you have rectangular orthogonal factors (so $P^TP=I$ but $PP^T\neq I$) or you have rectangular $S$ and you cannot invert it. In any case, the conditions do not imply $UV^T=0$.

Comment: If you don't believe me, take $W=\pmatrix{1&1&1\\0&1&0\\1&0&1}$, $U=\pmatrix{-1\\1\\1}$, $V=\pmatrix{-1\\0\\1}$. Then $U^TW=WV=0$ but $UV^T$ is obviously nonzero.

Comment: @AlgebraicPavel Thanks a lot for your detailed explanation and the counter-example, Of course I knew that $UV^{T}$ is nonzero and my question was related to know why I got the result, if I supposed that S is square of dimension equal to rank of W will my proof will still be wrong

Comment: You are welcome. Yes, if $S$ was supposed to be square of the size equal to the rank of $W$, then $P$ and $R$ are "tall" and rectangular so that $P^TP=R^TR=I$. In this case, $PP^T$ and $RR^T$ do not need to be equal to the identity though so from $P^TXR=0$ we cannot claim that $X=0$ (the mapping represented by $X$ is zero only on certain subspaces).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $U^TW=0$, we have
$$
A^TA=(VU^T+W^T)(UV^T+W)=VU^TUV^T+W^TW.
$$
Consider an $m$-vector $x$ and let $x=y+z$, where $y$ is in the range of $V$ and $z$ is orthogonal to $y$, that is, $z$ is in the nullspace of $V^T$ [hence $Wy=0$ (since $WV=0$) and $V^Tz=0$]. Then
$$
\begin{split}
x^TA^TAx&=(y+z)^T(VU^TUV^T+W^TW)(y+z)=y^TVU^TUV^Ty+z^TW^TWz
\\&\leq\sigma_{\max}(UV^T)^2\|y\|_2^2+\sigma_{\max}(W)^2\|z\|_2^2
\leq\left[\max\{\sigma_{\max}(UV^T),\sigma_{\max}(W)\}\right]^2\|x\|_2^2.
\end{split}
$$
Therefore,
$$
\sigma_{\max}(A)\leq\max\{\sigma_{\max}(UV^T),\sigma_{\max}(W)\}.
$$
The maximal singular value of $A$ will be given by that of $W$ if you can guarantee that the latter bounds from above that of $UV^T$.